# Comment extractor

Tags: python, c++, parsing, comments

I am looking for a command line tool or a library for C, C++, Python, or Node.js which can extract just the comments from source files in a wide variety of languages.

For instance, given "bob.c":

```
int main(){ //Here is a comment
  int i=3;  /*Another comment*/
}
```

The following should be returned:

```
Here is a comment
Another comment
```

Possibly with line numbers included.

This should work for "bob.py", "bob.js", "bob.css", "bob.rb", "bob.asm", and so on.

This question differs from [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889771/how-to-extract-comment-out-of-header-file-using-python-perl-or-sed) because I am interested not only in C-style comments, but others as well.

Additionally, I am *deeply suspicious* of regular expressions as a solution. Comment-esque phrases can be sited within quoted text in deeply convoluted ways; I have yet to see a regex solution on SO addressing this.

Comment: [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/)?

Comment: I don't expect the comments to necessarily have any kind of structured format.

Comment: Perhaps using [regex](https://regex101.com/r/fE0gP4/2)?

Comment: @QuaxtonHale, that way definitely lies darkness. Almost every answer on SO suggesting using regex to extract comments is wrong. Most languages include quote-delimited text which may contain phrases that a simple regex would think were comments. You can build complicated regex, but, by the time you have handled all of the special cases, you have created an incomprehensible mess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract comment out of header file using python, perl, or sed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889771/how-to-extract-comment-out-of-header-file-using-python-perl-or-sed)

Comment: Not a duplicate, @KronoS. That question asks only about C-style comments.

Comment: Also, the second answer on that page links to a Python library which also erroneously identifies the following as a comment: `printf("//This is not a comment!");`

Comment: If you want to process a wide variety of languages, you'll either need to decide they fall into categories (C-like, with C style comments,  COBOL with COBOL style comments, ...) and build one lexer for each.  The details of such lexers might get tricky, if the language has lot of odd lexical syntax (PHP is pretty gross on this front, check out interpolated strings).  ...

Comment: If you want one off the shelf, our Source Code Search Engine provides large scale search by lexing and indexing the code base you give it; it has lexers for some 40+ languages and dialects; it is trivial to ask it to find all comments (or any other token) and export them all as search hits. See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine

Comment: @IraBaxter: that tool is almost exactly what I was thinking of, though it seems to be non-free and (possibly) lacking a command line interface, which would make using it for batch jobs difficult. Your (extremely) helpful comments led to uncovering Pygments, which seems as though it could be crafted into a solution. I'd be happy to upvote your suggestion should you leave it as an answer.

Comment: Yep, leveraging a good open source LSE may help.  Notepad++, gedit spring to mind.  Even nano or vim.  Look into how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a table of regular expressions with any of python, C++, grep, etc., ad nauseum, keep in mind that many languages have multiple comment types and that some types of comments, (in some languages), can be multiline.  Line numbers can be returned easily.

Take a look at the python re library documentation as a starting point.

Comment: That way definitely lies darkness. Almost every answer on SO suggesting using regex to extract comments is wrong. Most languages include quote-delimited text which may contain phrases that a simple regex would think were comments. You can build complicated regex, but, by the time you have handled all of the special cases, you have created an incomprehensible mess.

Comment: I'm with Steve on this one.  If you had to *parse* the language, regexes would not work.  However, it turns out one defines lexers using pretty much regular expressions; see any standard lexer generator.   There are exotic cases where regex doesn't work, but by an large if you can define *all* the lexemes for a langauge with a lexer, you can certainly filter out all the ones that are not comments to satisy OP's request.  In fact, by merging the regexes for all non-comment tokens, you can effectively define a lexer with just two lexemes:  COMMENT and OTHERSTUFF.  That's pretty easy to filter.

Comment: ... you might have to write some ugly hacks (as one finds in almost every lexer) to deal with nasty things like PHP's docstrings, where the character sequence that opens the string, also closes it; you can't express that with regex.  But it you are willing to build lexers by classical schemes, building special lexers that extract just the comments for any language isn't hard; for N langauge, build N such lexers.

Comment: @Richard: To your point, if you define a conventional lexer, you will discover that in fact you write a lot of lexical expressions to cover all the lexemes in the language, each with its own special cases.  Most people don't think of lexers defined by regexes as incomprehensible messes; rather, they think of them as an organized way to manage dozens and dozens of regular expressions.  Yes, for many languages,  you will need that complexity if you do all the lexemes; less so if you are merging all the uninteresting ones, but the merged regex could be quite a big one.

Comment: @IraBaxter: what you have said is very true, and I appreciate it. My hesitation has been that SO is a wasteland of regexes that will not get the job done, the answer to which has typically been to build more complicated regexes. But, you are right, there are ways to organize the approach so that they form a well-architected whole. Upvoting Steve now.

Answer (score 1):

With helpful suggestions from Ira Baxter, I tracked down Pygments via searching for lexers.

Pygments understands a [massive number of languages](http://pygments.org/languages/) and converts input in any one of this languages to standardized HTML output appropriate for highlighting.

The following takes a path to a directory, searches it recursively for code files, and returns a dictionary of filenames and the comments within each file:

```py
import glob
import io
import os
import pathlib

import git
from pygments.formatter import Formatter
import pygments
import pygments.lexers



class CommentExtractor(Formatter):
  def __init__(self, **options):
    Formatter.__init__(self, **options)
  def format(self, tokensource, outfile):
    for ttype, value in tokensource:
      if ttype in pygments.token.Comment:
        outfile.write(value)



def GetCommentsFromFile(path):
  lexer = pygments.lexers.get_lexer_for_filename(path)
  comments = io.StringIO()
  pygments.highlight(
    code      = open(path,'r').read(),
    lexer     = lexer,
    formatter = CommentExtractor(), 
    outfile   = comments
  )
  return comments.getvalue()



def GetCommentsFromFiles(rootpath, excluded):
  files = {}
  for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(rootpath):
    #Skip hidden directories
    dirnames[:] = [d for d in dirnames if not d.startswith('.')]
    for filename in filenames:
      if filename.startswith('.'):       #Skip hidden files
        continue
      if pathlib.Path(filename).suffix in excluded:
        continue
      filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
      try:
        files[filename] = GetCommentsFromFile(filename)
      except pygments.util.ClassNotFound:
        pass
  return files



excluded_files_types = {".md", ".yml", ".bat", ".sh"}

files_and_comments = GetCommentsFromFiles(
  rootpath = "root_of_code_directories",
  excluded = excluded_files_types
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[OP requested this posted as an answer]

If you want to process a wide variety of languages, you'll either need to decide they fall into categories (C-like, with C style comments, COBOL with COBOL style comments, ...) and build one lexer for each. The details of such lexers might get tricky, if the language has lot of odd lexical syntax (PHP is pretty gross on this front, check out interpolated strings).

If you want one off the shelf, our Source Code Search Engine provides large scale search by lexing and indexing the code base you give it; it has lexers for some 40+ languages and dialects; it is trivial to ask it to find all comments (or any other token) and export them all as search hits to a hit log file. (The command for this is literally the letter "C" [for Comments] after turning on the log).

[Answering an additional question].  It has both GUI and command line interfaces.